# How to convert a square texture into a trapezoid texture with progressive distortion in GLSL

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Im in a Three.js project and Im trying to convert a square with a square texture inside into a trapezoid.
I manage to create the shape but the texture inside, although it fits/cover the shape it do it with an undesired distorsión.

Im using a PlaneBufferGeometry with ShaderMaterial and im trying to obtain this distorsion in the shader part (although it would be ok if it is done in the threejs geometry part).

This is my vertex:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){

    float scaleTOP = 0.5;
    float scaleBOTTOM = 1.0;
    float scaleLEFT = 1.0;
    float scaleRIGHT = 1.0;

    float scaleX = mix(scaleBOTTOM, scaleTOP, uv.y);
    float posX = position.x*scaleX;

    float scaleY = mix(scaleLEFT, scaleRIGHT, uv.x);
    float posY = position.y*scaleY;

    vec3 finalPosition = vec3(posX, posY);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( finalPosition, 1.0 );

    // Varyings:
    vUv = uv;
}
```

And this is my fragment:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 tex = texture2D ( uTexture, vUv );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex.g, tex.b, 1.0);

}
```

Unfortunately I manage to distort the square into the trapezoid but the texture is not distorted in the way I want. See figure to see the intended result:
[Figure:](https://www.robertoferrero.es/stackoverflow-images/glsl-square-2-trapezoid.jpg)

Comment: If you want it at the level of geometry's vertices, use bilinear interpolation. For reference: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/trilinear-interpolation-of-vertices/7991

Comment: @prisoner849 many thanks. That link was very useful. It put me on track of this one:
 [link](https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/NVVJBW). Having a correct working example helped me to find my error which was I was using only 1 division (two polygons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vertex and fragment were ok.
The problem was that the Threejs geometry I was using had only 2 polygons. I was using:

```
this.bg_geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height, 1, 1)
```

Thats it... with only one division which only created two triangles which actually can be seen in the figure I posted.
I changed the geometry to:

```
this.bg_geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height, 100, 100)
```

...and now the texture is distorted as desired.

Anyway many thanks to @prisoner849 as he put me in the track to pass 4 points as uniforms uPoints in this order: TL,TR,BL,BR to set the shape of the plane.
My vertex shader looks now like this:

```
uniform vec3 uPoints[4];
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){
    vec3 baselineBottom = (uPoints[3] - uPoints[2]) * uv.x + uPoints[2];
    vec3 baselineTop = (uPoints[1] - uPoints[0]) * uv.x + uPoints[0];
    vec3 finalPosition = (baselineTop - baselineBottom) * uv.y + baselineBottom;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( finalPosition, 1.0 );
    vUv = uv;
}
```